# Securing DB and session-data on a PHP shared host

Tags: php, security, apache, session, shared-hosting

I wrote a PHP web-application using `SQLite` and sessions stored on `filesystem`.

This is functionally fine and attractively low maintenance.  But, now it needs to run on a shared host.

All web-applications on the shared host run as the same user, so my users' session data is vulnerable, as is the database, code, etc.

Many recommend storing sessions in `DBMS` such as `MySQL` in this situation.  So at first I thought I will just do that, and move the `SQLite` data into `MySQL` too.  But then I realized the `MySQL` credentials need to be readable by the web application user, so I'm back to square one.

I think the best solution is to use `PHP` as a `CGI` so it runs as different user for each web-application.  This sounds great, but my host does not do this it uses `mod_php`.  Are there any drawbacks from an admin's point-of-view for enabling this? (performance, backward compatibility, etc)?  If not then I will ask them to enable this.

Otherwise, is there anything I can do to secure my database and session data in this situation?

Answer (score 4):

As long as your code is running as the shared web user, anything stored on the server is going to be vulnerable.  Any other user could write a PHP script to examine any readable file on the server, including your data and PHP code.

If your hosting provider will allow it, running as PHP as a CGI under a different user will help, but I expect there will be a significant performance hit, as each request will require a new process to be created.  (You could look at FCGI as a better-performing alternative.)

The other approach would be to set a cookie based on something the user provides, and use that to encrypt session data.  For instance, when the user logs in, take a hash of their username, password (as just supplied by them) and the current time, encrypt the session data with the hash, set a cookie containing the hash.  On the next request, you'll get the cookie back, which you can then use to decrypt the session data.  Note however that this will only protect the current session data; your user table, other data, and code will still be vulnerable.

In this situation, you need to decide whether the tradeoff of the low cost of shared hosting is acceptable considering the reduced security it provides.  This will depend on your application, and it may be that rather than trying to come up with a complex (and possibly not even very effective) way to add security, you're better off just accepting the risk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't view security as all or nothing. There are steps you can take. Give the web db user only the permissions it needs. Store passwords as hashes. Use openid login so users provide their credentials over SSL.

PHP on cgi can be slower and some hosts may simply not want to support more than one environment.

You may need to stick with your host for some reason, but generally there are so many available that it is a good reminder for people to compare functionality and security as well as cost. I have noticed many companies starting to offer virtual machine hosting -- nearly dedicated server level security in terms of isolating your code from other users -- at what is to me reasonable cost.

Answer (score 0):

A shared host is no way to run a web site if you are conscious about privacy and security of your data from the sites that you share the server with. Anything accessible to your web application is fair game for the others; it'll only be a matter of time before they can access it (assuming they do have incentive to do that to you).

Answer (score 0):

"you can place your DB connection variables in a file below the web root. this will at least protect it from web access. if you're going to use file based sessions as well, you can set the session path in your user's directory and again outside the web root."

I don't have an account so I can't downvote that.. but seriously it is not even relevant to the question.

Duh you store stuff outside the webroot.  That goes for any hosting scenario and is not specific to shared hosting.  We're not talking about protecting from outsiders here.  We're talking about protecting from other applications on the same machine.

To the OP I think PHP as CGI is the most secure solution, as you already suggested yourself.  But as someone else said there is a performance hit with this.

Something you might look at is moving your sessions and db to MySQL and using safe_mode and/or open_basedir.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem with a infrasturcture change instead of a code one.
Consider upgrading to a VPS server.  Nowdays you can get them very inexpensive.  I've seen VPS's starting @ 10$/mo.